# Circular countdown JavaScript from 10 to Zero

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to reverse the countdown in this demo from 10 down to zero Without luck.

I have tried reversing the countdown by doing this:

```
(1*(initialOffset/time))-initialOffset )
```

It did reverse the animated circle but not the countdown.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```js
var time = 10;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 1

/* Need initial run as interval hasn't yet occured... */
$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('h2').text(i);
    if (i == time) {   
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
    i++;  
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
    stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
    stroke-dashoffset: 440;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <h2>0</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Here is also a codepen copy:

https://codepen.io/kaolay/pen/LRVxKd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$('h2').text(time - i);` instead of `$('h2').text(i);`

I also added `$('h2').text(time);` as the 4th line to draw `10` at the beginning

Also, the first part of the circle is not animated in your code, so I changed this line:

```
$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));
```

To this block:

```
$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset);
setTimeout(() => {
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));
})
```

```js
var time = 10;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 1;
$('h2').text(time); // adding 10 at the beginning if needed

/* Need initial run as interval hasn't yet occured... */
$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset);
setTimeout(() => {
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));
})


var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('h2').text(time - i); // here is the clue
    if (i == time) {   
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
    i++;  
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
    stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
    stroke-dashoffset: 440;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <h2>0</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you update this line `$('h2').text(time - i);` then you'll get the numeric countdown. I also initalize `i = 0` so that the starting number is `10`:

```js
var time = 10;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 0

/* Need initial run as interval hasn't yet occured... */
$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('h2').text(time - i);
  if (i == time) {   
      clearInterval(interval);
   return;
    }
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
    i++;  
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
    <h2>0</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you asking here?
"It did reverse the animated circle but not the countdown."

you are just trying to countdown?

why not set i = 10 and then do i--

Comment: because of animation, it also depends on `i`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invert the animation just invert all states of initial values and change i to (time-i). So it goes like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <h2>10</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
    </svg>
</div>

.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

var time = 10;
var initialOffset = 440;
var i = 0

/* Need initial run as interval hasn't yet occured... */
$('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', 0);

var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $('h2').text(time-i);
        if (i == time) {    
      clearInterval(interval);
            return;
    }
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset*i/time);
    i++;  

}, 1000);
```

Code pen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xybpge